# value of discrete items when only have their value when sold in groups

Tags: computational-statistics

I'm doing an analysis for my job and would greatly appreciate any help you can offer!

My company sells pallets full of items. Each item has a category (1 category per item, many items per category) and each item has a retail value. We are liquidators so the pallets get sold for much less than the sum of the retail values they contain. In the model I'm building, the sale price of an item predicted by its retail value ($V$) and it's recovery rate ($R$, the percentage of retail for which the item sells). This means that a pallet sale price ($P$) should be

$P = \sum{V_i \times R_i}$

where the index $i$ is iterated over every item in the pallet.

Given a large data set with a large number of $P$, and also the $V_i$ that correspond to each $P$, I am trying to find some average $R_i$ for each category - or some way of measuring this $R_i$ or even describing it at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is well-suited to analysis by a linear model. Let $n$ be the number of pallets sold for which you have data, let $m$ be the number of categories, let $X$ be an $n \times m$ matrix where $X_{ij}$ represents the quantity of items of category $j$ contained in pallet $i$, and let $P$ be a vector of $n$ elements, where $P_i$ is the price of pallet $i$. You can set up the linear model as follows, as a vector equation:

$$ P = X\beta + \epsilon$$

where $\beta$ is an unknown vector of $m$ elements, giving the expected price of each category of item when sold in a pallet by your company, and $\epsilon$ is a vector of random errors, modeling the variation from the expected total prices.

There is an enormous literature on linear models, which you may want to look into, but to give you a quick answer: the most widely used approach from here would be to apply least-squares regression, which estimates $\beta$ as
$$\hat\beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TP$$
From there you would estimate $R_i = \hat \beta_i/V_i$.